# Why would an executable stop working with popen in python

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I have been running flow models using an executable that must be placed in the directory containing the inputs. I used subprocess.popen() to run the executable in several different folders, the executable uses the working directory to determine the location of the input and output files. I could successfully run the models in batches until the developer's latest update, now the model will not run using the code below which worked for the last version of the exe.

```
# Worked before latest exe version
dir = r"C:\Users\me\Documents\Models\Model1"
exe_fp = os.path.join(dir, "FLO.exe")
process = subprocess.Popen(exe_fp, cwd=dir)
```

If I open windows explorer and double-click the executable it runs, if I create a .BAT file in another directory that changes the working directory to the model directory and call the executable, it runs when I double click the .BAT file, but not when the .BAT file is called using subprocess.call() or subprocess.popen() similar to script above.

I'm guessing it has something to do with environmental variables, but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the developer and was able to identify the solution. In my case there was a missing DLL causing the issue.